# How to avoid vertical scroll bar in an ipad application

Tags: css

I am developing an e-commerce app for ipad both in landscape and portrait orientation. The main content div in the middle of the layout will have all the products displayed side by side. I have written media queries for both landscape and portrait. They are working fine, but I am getting a vertical scroll bar because of the content div (I think). I want to avoid the vertical scroll scroll bar completely.

top left: logo

next div: title

next div: products----I think the problem is with this div only.

nextdiv: footer

I can't send the picture because I have less than 10 reputations.

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: we do your homework??

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
html{overflow-y: hidden;} if you want scrollbar disabled for your html.
```